# PayPal mobile express checkout - shipping methods

Tags: mobile, paypal

I'm running into some problems regarding the usage of shipping methods in the PayPal mobile express checkout API: I submit multiple shipping methods via the API to the checkout form.

The form is rendered correctly at the PayPal side, but as soon as I select a shipping method from the list, I get redirected to my return_url.

How come? Shouldn't the checkout form be still visible and I would need to select 'Continue' at the bottom?

[edit]
As requested, below is a screenshot of the PayPal form. When I click any of the shipping option buttons, I'm forwarded to the return url (with the correct shipping method, however, but without clicking the "Continue" button at the bottom).

[image: Mobile PayPal form]

Comment: Can you post the form?

Comment: @Machavity attached above!

Comment: My apologies. I meant can you post the HTML?

Comment: I guess you don't need the HTML of the PayPal form!? On my side, there's no form, just a button which forwards to PayPal with a token value, generated by a previous API call to PayPal.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thinking this was from Payments Standard. I'm not sure anyone but PayPal could explain why that happens. They are the ones who control the flow of Express Checkout